# How to upgrade .Net framework 4.6.2 to 4.7

Tags: upgrade

My solution is developed in .net framework **4.6.2**  then how to upgrade in .net framework **4.7**, please suggest me some references.

Thank You

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue because I was trying to install a nuget package which requires the 4.6.1 version at least (Mine was 4.5.2), so I right clicked to the project and selected the  properties option and change the Target Framework as shown in the image and that was enough! Keep in mind that you have to install previously the Net. Framework you are trying to upgrade.

[image: Change the framework]

Comment: By the way be aware to upgrade your installed nuget packages as needed.

Answer (score 1):

As per this document from Microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/

> *If you created your app using an earlier version of the .NET Framework, you can generally upgrade it to the .NET Framework 4.5 and its point releases (4.5.1 and 4.5.2), the .NET Framework 4.6 and its point releases (4.6.1 and 4.6.2), or the .NET Framework 4.7 and its point releases (4.7.1 and 4.7.2) easily. Open your project in Visual Studio. If your project was created in an earlier version of Visual Studio, the Project Compatibility dialog box automatically opens.*

You should review the above document to better understand how to migrate your .NET version as required.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the migration guide was not helpful. I needed to:

1. Open my solution
2. Right click on my project and choose "Properties"
3. Change the "Target Framework" to the desired choice of ".NET
   Framework 4.7.2"

Answer (score 1):

1.Open Solution

2.Right click on my project

3.Choose "Properties" and Change the "Target Framework" to the desired choice of ". NET Framework 4.7. 2"

It will work

Answer (score 1):

*Follow these steps to upgrade the .NET Framework:*

1. Right-click on your project solution folder.
2. Select the 'Properties' tab.
3. Select the 'Target Framework' to desired .NET Framework.

Use these tools by Microsft for the Framework degradation process:

- [https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant-now-in-visual-studio/][1]

**Note**: If get any errors regarding the reference libraries and some DLL errors make sure to check all the DLLs from the reference folder should be compatible with the upgraded version of .NET.